# Unchangeable gnome panels

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic

I have a new install of Ubuntu 14.04 and Gnome classic and it appears to be impossible to change the panels.

One of them is stuck at the top of the screen... you used to be able to hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and drag it. I really really really do not want it to be at the top of the screen.

It also seems to be impossible to add launchers to the panels. Right-clicking does nothing, alt-right-click does nothing, alt+windows-right-click does nothing.

Any ideas on how to change the panels? I've been fighting this and scouring the internet for answers for about 5 hours now.

Answer (score 0):

What's called *Gnome Classic* is build with same GUI backend of *Gnome Shell*.

It seems to me what you are looking for is called now *Gnome Fallback* or *Gnome Flashback* which is still using `metacity`. To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```